# Spigot server not writing to config file

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, bukkit-vault

I am making an economy system for my spigot Minecraft 1.8.8 server, and because a hashmap resets every time I reload the server (erasing everybody $ data), I am trying to use the config file. A problem I'm having though is that my server won't write to the config file, or I just cannot see it, as it still appears blank although the processes are working fine. I would be fine with this, although it might be causing a bigger problem, the config file being wiped every time I reload. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any code it's hard to know what's wrong but i guess maybe you aren't saving the file? (yamlConfigurationInstance.save(yourfile);)

If thats not the problem please provide a bit more code.